# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView.... inspite of calling notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listactivity

What are the best practices to be followed to update the contents of a listactivty by a background thread (Async Task) ?

1) Am calling the **notifyDataSetChanged()** to update the adapter as soon as i manipulate the contents of the adapter but still my app force closes while the user scrolls or click on the list. Any pointers to prevent this would be very helpfull.

Logcat:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

2) Where exaclty should i update contents of the listactivity ? inside the doInBackground() or onProgressUpdate()?

3) Am experiencing regular crashes when the user clicks the list item. So will disabling click events on the listactivty during the background operation solve the problem ? If so am not sure how to remove or set item click listeners dynamically to the listactivity. Please instruct me on the too.

4) I dont think blocking all ui interactions during the background async task execution is the only way to solve the problem. I know there is a simple way of doing this but need some help.

Thanks in advance.

This is my onCreate...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fa);

tvStatus=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        mostPopularList,
        R.layout.list_item,
        new String[] {"title","author","views","date"},
        new int[] {R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView4,R.id.textView3});
        //populateList();


        setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

My async task...

```
          private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // code for adding new listactivty items 
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String networkStatus) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {

          }

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

           }
          }
```

Logcat:

i rarely the the illegalstate exception too... not able to reproduce it. will post the logcat if i come across it again.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:147)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:623)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2944)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2065)
    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3315)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

Comment: what about listView.postInvalidate() ?

Comment: please post post log cat for better understanding of the rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) Where exaclty should i update contents of the listactivity ? inside the doInBackground() or onProgressUpdate()?

Inside `onProgressUpdate()` or inside onPostExecute() because it could take some time since you change content in `doInBackground()` and call async task calls your

```
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String networkStatus) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
```

> 3) Am experiencing regular crashes when the user clicks the list item. So will disabling click events on the listactivty during the background operation solve the problem ? If so am not sure how to remove or set item click listeners dynamically to the listactivity. Please instruct me on the too.

It is not a solution. You just need update your dataset on UI thread. (Not load content, just update from old to a new one). For example

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
           List<String> items = loadUpdatedDataset(params);
           return items;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(List<String> loadedItems) {
        updateAdapterDataset(loadedItems);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

       }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, check it out in this class. There is a great example using AsyncTask and Listview
http://android.okhelp.cz/java_android_code.php?o=%5Candroid-15%5CGestureBuilder%5Csrc%5Ccom%5Candroid%5Cgesture%5Cbuilder%5CGestureBuilderActivity.java#Problem.

I believe that problem in your code is because the adapter is updating your ListView and at this moment the user click in the ListView causing the crash in your application.

Comment: I too thought the same. But i don't have a on itemclick listener for my listactivty. More over sometimes i get the following error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0. I suspect the crash happens on scroll :-(

Answer (score 1):

This exception is misleading - there are many causes.
One cause for this crash is that ArrayList object cannot change completely.
So, when I remove an item, I have to do this:

```
mList.clear();
mList.addAll(newDataList);
```

This fixed the crash for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem annoys me for a long time.

When I use `MotionEvent` to click the `listView` before invoke `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`,it do cause *Illegalstate Exception*.

So I think it's useful to invoke `ListView.setEnable`(false) before update `listView`.