# on listView fast scroll i get : The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview in fragment class and an custom arrayadapter for the list view. i took data from json and display it on listview. and i load more data on listview when listview scroll to end.

its works good when i run this application in api level 14 but in api level 8 when i scroll listview slow it works ok again but when i scroll fast it gives me error like...

```
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034206, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1492)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:743)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 10:48:17.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I need help on it...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12978660/1265724. It may help you..

Comment: Post your code here please